# Transfer PDF in iBooks from iPhone to iPad

Tags: ipad, iphone, books

How do I transfer a PDF I've saved in iBooks from my iPhone 6 to my iPadPro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

**If you're using iCloud Drive**, opening *iBooks*, scrolling to the item (a PDF, ePub or book) and tapping on the *Download* icon will download the item to your library. If you're not currently using *iCloud Drive* you can always turn it on under **Settings / iCloud / iCloud Drive**.

**Syncing through a Computer**. If both devices are synced with the same computer, you could go into iTune's device's *Settings* and enable *Sync Books*. Then syncing both devices would share the item. Bear in mind that if iTunes is set to *sync only selected books*, you'll need to manually check the checkbox next to the PDF you want to sync.

**Send the file attached to an Email**. Attaching the PDF to an email, opening it from the *other* device and saving the PDF file into iBooks would do the trick, too.

Comment: It worked for the purchased book but not for the PDF

Comment: @Mauro74 Right. I've updated the answer to provide more options.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your iPhone and iPad to the latest version of iOS (9.3 or later) and turning on **iCloud for iBooks**. PDFs and books will automatically sync between your devices.

Also, Thecafremo provides some good ideas as well; email is a particularly good method as well.